# OS X: Saving open application states

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, macos, savestate

Apple introduced a new feature where when you shut down the PC you have the choice to save open application states, so when you log in next time they're opened automatically. I found the files it saves at `~/Library/Saved Application States`.

I wanted to know if third party developers can save states of other application? That is save the current state of a specified application, that can be restored at will in future. If so how, I couldn't find any documentation about it. Any simple example or resources would be very helpful.

My aim is a create a script/utility that save state of say *Safari*, and use this information to recreate all the windows, tabs etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find any documentation about it

It's documented in [Apple's Programming Guide for Core App Design](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I meant documentation to exploit that feature and not implement it in an application. I want a way to get all the required data about an app to save and use later.

Comment: I suggest rewording your question as it's not clear. You state Apple's feature and then ask *"...if third party developers can do that exactly"*..... *"My aim is a create a script/utility that does that*". The documentation describes how to do what the question asks. What do you mean by *"to exploit that feature and not implement it in an application?"*

Comment: Definitely clearer and to further answer the question, Apple is unlikely to provide an API for that, so you'd need to work out the format of the two binary files are and update those, along with the relevant plist file.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Do you have recommendations for any tools or specific place (obviously Google would be decent start) where I can information regarding binary files? I've never dealt with them before.

Comment: I expect the format of those will not be documented.